# Use lambda function trigger at S3 create file to run c++ code on Cloud9

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda

I want to run a c++ code to process a image that is stored on Aws S3.
Can it be done? If yes... how?

```
import boto3
region = 'us-east-1'
instances = ['i-08f007160c7ddd4ba']

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=region)
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. There are a lot of tutorials out there, [here is an official tutorial on S3 + Lambda integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3-example.html)

To summarize what's required:

1. Deploy the Lambda that will process the image(s)
2. Create an S3 bucket
3. Create an event trigger in S3 for the Lambda

That's it, once you have this, the moment you upload the file the Lambda will get triggered with an event that contains the file prefix (file name essentially), and then your Lambda can get the file (based on the prefix in the event) and process it